# Is it possible to set a timeout on the expanded tree cache in MarkLogic?

Tags: caching, marklogic

I am trying to figure out why the hosts in my E-Node cluster are always climbing in memory. One of the lines of inquiry is if the cache isn't being cleared periodically. So far I have not seen any way to specify a timeout on entries in the cache, nor how to set a max age on those entries. Is this even possible?

Comment: You said that the memory is always climbing. Over how long of a period of time? Have you hit any limits? If it is within the configured limits, then it could just be caches warming. Is it causing any issues? If you have memory available, then you want the server to use it.

Comment: We are consistently seeing the memory utilization warm up after a reboot, which I believe is expected, but then it keeps creeping up over time and after 7 days it goes from about 60% utilization to 80%. At this point the server starts having other performance issues and needs to be rebooted.

Comment: You had said this issue was with your E-node. Have you looked at what sort of queries you are running against it? If the E-node is consistently running at 60-80%, it could be that you are returning giant result sets and might look at pagination, or are selecting a huge temporary set to return a subset and might look to optimize queries. Either that, or you are just way under provisioned.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks for the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a timeout setting for the caches.

A maximum size is configured for the various caches for the group. When you allocate memory for the server to use, you should expect that it will be used. It helps the server run faster and more efficiently. MarkLogic will manage the cache and evict "old" entries if it needs to make room for "new" entries in order to stay within the configured maximum size.

You can return the status of the caches with [`xdmp:cache-status()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:cache-status) to observe how much is being used.

If you do want to clear the expanded tree cache, you can invoke `xdmp:expanded-tree-cache-clear()` on each host, as demonstrated in this [knowledgebase article](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/543/0/clearing-the-expanded-tree-cache-on-each-host-when-redeploying-xml-schemas-in-marklogic-server).

Take a look at the Meters data in the Monitoring History and click on the blue arrow next to the Memory section, in order to drill down and look at the Memory Detail to observe the pattern of memory consumption for each of the components of server memory.

Answer (score 0):

A little more on cache status: https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/253/0/monitoring-cache-status-with-xdmpcache-status

However, as noted above, the ETC is configured to a max size in the group settings.